Firestore rules to not allow additional queries
getDocs(query(orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')))

with rules, i can enforce a query
allow list: if request.query.orderBy.createdAt == "DESC"


How do i make it so users cannot apply query to any other fields
getDocs(query(orderBy('createdAt', 'desc'), where('status', '==', 0)))

status is an additional query

And how do i make it so users may apply queries to specific fields
so...

createdAt ==> Enforce
price ==> User may add it
[any other fields] ==> Do not allow user to apply any sort of queries to it


Hmmm... valid question. I'm actually not sure if this is possible, but would love to see other's take. You might want to clarify the use-case a bit, as in: what business requirement is violated with that second query that isn't violated with the first?

@FrankvanPuffelen, if there is a limit() in the query, it would make it easier for "x" to access specific documents by adding an extra where query.

Please add the clarification to the question, as fewer folks are likely to see it in comment.s
